# Excel 2016 - Using Get Data to import CSV and format to show in a different column in the worksheet

Tags: formatting, excel-2016, import-from-csv

Currently I have a CSV file that I am trying to import into excel using Get Data, and format to show each value separated in a different column within the excel workbook.  I have the CSV with the values separated in the file in such a way as seen below:

*VBU|"VBU Name"|"PO Number"|"Customer Order Number"|"Line Number"|"Insert Date/Time"|"Ack Date"|"Confirm Date"|"Company Item Number"|"Vendor Model Number"|"Quantity Ordered"|"Line Status"|"Back Order Reason"|"Cancel Reason"|"Origin State"|"Destination State"|"Tracking Number"|"Expected Delivery Date"|"Expected Ship Date"|"Actual Ship Date"*

I am having a hard time separating each value into it's separate column in the excel workbook after importing it using the Get Data - From Text/CSV.

Is there a step I am missing like a custom delimiter for instance, in order to have this imported and formatted in such a way that each column shows the individual value (column 1 = VBU, column 2 = VBU Name, Column 3 = PO Number), etc.?  This CSV file, all these values are crammed into the first column when I open the CSV in excel 2016.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was an anomally in one file.  Using Get Data -> From File -> From Text/CSV and setting delimiter as | did the trick and I was able to transform it and separate the values into different columns